# Change background color and image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a square with a logo inside. On hover in the square, I want the background color to change as well as the color of the logo.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
 <div class="project", id="project1">
  <a href="#" ><img class="pure-img" src="/media/logo.png" onmouseover="this.src='/media/logo2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/media/logo.png'" width="80px" height="78px" alt="logo"></a>
 </div>
</div>

.project {
  background-color: #f5f4f4;
  margin: 0 0.5em 2em;
  padding: 4em 4em;
}

#project1:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I can get the logo to change on hover and I can get the square to change, but I can't get them to both change at the same time, i.e. when the mouse touches the square.

I'm assuming this needs javascript, which I do not know. Any tips/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can do this only in css, just using background-image: url();     and the pseudo element :hover

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JavaScript required, just CSS. No need for an `<img>` either.

```html
<div class="logo">Brand Name</div>
```

```css
.logo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 78px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    background-image: url('http://s17.postimg.org/7hltqe5e3/sprite.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
.logo:hover {
    background-color: red;
    background-position: -80px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/12u7ma2q/

Create a sprite with both versions of the logo side-by-side. When you hover you will change the background color and shift the position of the sprite image (left, right, up, down - depends on how you created your sprite).

---

The benefits to this  answer over *sailens* is that you're not using invalid markup (`<img>` without a `src` attribute) and you're only making a single request for an image instead of two. Oh, and less markup - a single `<div>` (which could be an `<a>`, `<span>` etc).

You could also shorten `.logo` by using [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) instead of individual background properties. I listed them out at first for clarity.

```css
.logo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 78px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    background: blue url('http://s17.postimg.org/7hltqe5e3/sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/12u7ma2q/1/

Comment: This is indeed a more complete answer, it goes far beyond the question _per se_

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner HTML (since img tag needs a source, you can change it for a div):

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
  <div class="project", id="project1">
   <div class="pure-img">
  </div>
 </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.project {
  background-color: #f5f4f4;
  margin: 0 0.5em 2em;
  padding: 4em 4em;
}

#project1:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.pure-img{
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
    width: 80px; 
    height: 78px;


}

#project1:hover .pure-img {
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400/666/0011fc);
}
```

and the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/h6gwwox6/1/

Comment: Thanks. I get the same result with my code although yours is cleaner. What I want is the logo to change color at the same time as the mouse arrow touches the red area in your fiddle. Does that make sense? Right now, you need to hover over the logo for it to change color.

Comment: Image elements should have a `src` attribute and therefore is not valid. Use a different element.

Comment: @hungerstar I agree, but I think the answer to the question is made. I will update the answer though