# When hovering the div ,change photo data-bg

Tags: html, css, hover

```
    <div class="slide-background a" style="" data-bg="images/1new.jpg">
    </div>
```

I want when hovering the div to change smoothly the data-bg photo

i tried to hover with css

```
  div.slide-background.a:hover{;background-image: url("../images
  /1newcolor.jpg") !important;}
```

but i want a smoothly change.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: can't do anything without jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change background color and image on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238260/change-background-color-and-image-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with jquery...

```
$( ".slide-background" ).hover(function() {
      $(".slide-background").attr("data-bg", "some_other_img.jpg");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with jquery,

```
$(".slide-background").hover(function()
{
   $(".slide-background").attr("data-bg", "url.jpg");
});
```